# Why Reduce Helper is returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, reduce, helper

I tried this code on [this website](https://stephengrider.github.io/JSPlaygrounds/) and it worked fine and returned 60 as it should, but when I try to run it on an HTML web page, first it returns 10 and the other 2 values would be NaN, I don't understand why this error happens.
I would appreciate your solutions.

```js
var numbers = [ 10, 20, 30 ] ;

numbers.reduce(function(sum , number){
     return console.log( sum + number);
} , 0);
```

Comment: You forgot to `return number` in the reduce function

Comment: ....if that first hint does not help, please add your debugging attempts to the question by editing

Comment: @NicoHaase Hey, I did that and I see nothing in the console.

Comment: Its probably that your declaring number even though number is already a parameter. Also the hypertext in your post doesn't go anywhere...

Comment: What do you mean by "I did that"? Please share your debugging attempts

Comment: Also, `return console.log` does not help to sum up the numbers

Comment: @AjayChambers I checked what you mentioned and hit `return console.log( sum + number);` , still not working. The link is: https://stephengrider.github.io/JSPlaygrounds/

Comment: You are doing `undefined` + number resulting in NaN. Returning `sum` should fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah I was just gonna say you cant return the value in a console log. Because the callback is preformed for each number in the array, you must return the previous data computed via the return statement, and not in a console log.

Comment: Nobody suggested to return the result of `console.log`. Why not return `sum + number` if you want to sum up numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the reduce function you are returning `console.log()`. `console.log()` does not return anything (`undefined`), so your sum becomes undefined as well. `undefined + 10` will give you the `NaN` error.

If you want to see things in the console, *and* have the function work as intended, you will need to 1) return numbers and 2) include a `console.log` in your code. In other words, something like

```js
var numbers = [ 10, 20, 30 ] ;

numbers.reduce(function(sum , number){
     console.log(sum + number);
     return sum + number;
} , 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not return `console.log`. This always returns undefined:

```js
const numbers = [ 10, 20, 30 ] ;

numbers.reduce(function(sum , number) {
  console.log(sum + number);

  return sum + number;
} , 0);
```

Comment: Really? I dont think I ever returned console.log. Fun fact indeed.